# How to use Observables within a method full of if-branching

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

Many times I faced this issue while trying to be more reactive, I am not able to find a clean way to do it, to make this method returns an Observable.

this is the example code:

```
public updateItemEligibility(item: Item): void
{
        this.updateCalculations(item);
        if (item.status == Status.Full)
        {
            this.markEligibleItem(item);
        }

        if (item.quantity > 0 && item.Stage == 1)
        {
           const info: ItemInfo =  this.getAdditionalInfoFromApi(); // will uses observable
           if (info.Staged)
           {
               this.updateStagedCalculations(item);
           }
        }

        if (item.quantity == 0 && item.Stage == 2)
        {
           const stagingInfo: StagingInfo =  this.getStaginInfoFromApi();
           item.eligible = this.allowStagedItems && item.amount > 0 && stagingInfo.Stages[item.stage].Completed == true;
        }
        this.updateTotals(item);
}
```

The problem here is calling the API only if a condition is satisfied.

Comment: Please not that you method is doing a lot of things here that are quite different. From simple checks to an API call. You should create separate functions and then you can use Observables. Check this documentation for a better structure in general: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Also notice that another developer that uses your method "updateItemEligibility" is not aware of the fact that an API call is made. This is called a side effect and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want a method that returns an Observable that notifies when the `item` is updated (if it has to be updated).

If this is the case, then I would proceed as follows (the comments try to explain the logic)

```
 public updateItemEligibility(item: Item): Observable<Item> {
    // this initial part is untouched since I guess is all synchronous stuff
    this.updateCalculations(item);
    if (item.status == Status.Full) {
      this.markEligibleItem(item);
    }
    // here we start the ifs.
    if (item.quantity > 0 && item.Stage == 1) {
      // In the first case we want to return an Observable
      // that notifies after getAdditionalInfoFromApi has returned
      // we use the map operator to make this Oservable notify with the item as value
      // after performing all necessary things
      return this.getAdditionalInfoFromApi().pipe(
        map((info: ItemInfo) => {
          if (info.Staged) {
            this.updateStagedCalculations(item);
            this.updateTotals(item);
            return item;
          }
        })
      );
    }
    // here the second if
    if (item.quantity == 0 && item.Stage == 2) {
      // as we have done above, we return an Observable that notifies when getStaginInfoFromApi returns
      // (assuming that getStaginInfoFromApi returns an Oservable) and we use map
      // to make the Observable notify with item as value
      return this.getStaginInfoFromApi().pipe(
        map((stagingInfo: StagingInfo) => {
          item.eligible =
            this.allowStagedItems &&
            item.amount > 0 &&
            stagingInfo.Stages[item.stage].Completed == true;
          this.updateTotals(item);
          return item;
        })
      );
    }
    // if none of the conditions above is met, we return an
    // an Observable that notifies immediately with item as value
    // using the of function
    this.updateTotals(item);
    return of(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: good approach, but in case we have more logic in both if blocks, I think we will get in code clones in some of the if blocks, to keep the order of statements execution.

Comment: Can you make an example of code clones? consider that you can set a variable to the value of `pipe`s (which are functions) and so reuse the same variable across different pipe chains. But anyways, if you make an example it would be easier for me to understand your point.

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer This answer explains how to convert your code so it returns observables. If you have further questions, please ask a separate question with the code the exemplifies your issue. We prefer lean and focused questions which will be more useful to the rest of the community.